# Grouping by pairs of values that are interchangeably used

Tags: sql, oracle

So, basically I want to count the number of unique set of ID pairs. Here is the interactive demo.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa5e732b8e980358a84fa255e83114b5

**Data:**

| SENDER | RECEIVER | TRANSACTION ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 5678 | 1 |
| 1234 | 5678 | 4 |
| 5678 | 1234 | 5 |
| 5678 | 1234 | 9 |
| 5678 | 9876 | 12 |
| 9876 | 5678 | 7 |

**Desired output:**

| SENDER | RECEIVER | TRANSACTION COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 5678 | 4 |
| 5678 | 9876 | 2 |

**Or:**

| SENDER | RECEIVER | TRANSACTION COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 1234 | 4 |
| 9876 | 5678 | 2 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(sender, receiver) AS sender,
       GREATEST(sender, receiver) AS receiver,
       COUNT(*) AS transaction_count
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       LEAST(sender, receiver),
       GREATEST(sender, receiver)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (SENDER, RECEIVER, TRANSACTION_ID) AS
SELECT 1234, 5678,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 5678,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5678, 1234,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5678, 1234,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5678, 9876, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9876, 5678,  7 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SENDER | RECEIVER | TRANSACTION_COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5678 | 9876 | 2 |
> | 1234 | 5678 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=207e1398fbde9e026deda73e59b5d8fe)*

Comment: I am inclined to mark @jarlh's answer as accepted since he probably answered couple of seconds earlier. I appreciate your effort and quick reply, thank you.

Comment: @Larx - I understand the inclination, but...  To be within seconds of each other indicates they were essentially simultaneous; first by seconds is very arbitrary.  Also that drives negative behaviours by incentivising an answer's speed over it being complete, tested, well-formed, etc.  I'd rather ignore timestamps and accept an answer based on the other criteria mentioned here.  As this answer includes demonstration code and a db-fiddle, I'd suggest it is materially superior to the other answer, in that it has additional information that may assist future readers.

Comment: @MatBailie  I guess I unintentionally disregarded almost all the things you have stated. That was eye-opening and will also be taken into consideration in my future questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use least and greatest to get the lower value first:

```
select least(sender, receiver), greatest (sender, receiver), count(*)
from tablename
group by least(sender, receiver), greatest (sender, receiver)
```